# Allow someone to input a name that will be passed to a function that will use a binary search to see if that name is contained inside the list

Tags: python

Basically, I need to create a program that allows someone to input a name that will then be passed to a function that will use a binary search to see if that name is contained inside the list.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
def main():
    SIZE = 10
    names = ['Ava Fischer', 'Bob White', 'Chris Rich', 'Danielle Porter', 'Gordon Pike', 'Hannah Beauregard', 'Matt Hoyle', 'Ross Harrison', 'Sasha Ricci', 'Xavier Adams']

    searchName=input("Enter name to search for: ")
    index = binarySearch(names, searchName, SIZE)

    if index != -1:
        print ("The name is ", names(index))
    else:
        print (searchName,"was not found.")

def binarySearch(names, name, SIZE):
    first = 0
    last = SIZE - 1
    position = -1
    found = False


    while (not found) and (first <= last):
        middle = (first + last)/2

        if middle == name:
            found = True
            position = middle
        elif middle > name:
            last = middle - 1
        else:
            first = middle + 1

main()`
```

Sample run with error:

```
Enter name to search for: Ava Fischer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 6, in main
    index = binarySearch(names, searchName, SIZE)
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 26, in binarySearch
    elif middle > name:
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > str()
```

I realize why it's giving me the error, but I can't seem to figure out a way I can change my code to stop this error from happening.  Please implement a solution without altering my code too much please.  Keep in mind when you answer that I'm a complete newbie at programming, so be nice :)  It is 10pm here and this program is due by midnight, so I really could use some help here.  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're in a time crunch! I'm sure many coders would be glad to help, but since this is homework we're gonna need a little more understanding from you. Why do you think it's giving you the error?

Comment: It's giving me the error because I'm trying to perform an operation on an integer and a string, which is like saying "the+3=2" which obviously makes no sense.

Comment: So which two variables are wrong? How would you check which one is which?

Comment: What does ```middle``` represent?

Comment: From looking at the error output, I can see that the "middle" and "name" variables are conflicting and causing this error.  Obviously because the input of "name" is a string value and the "middle" variable is an integer.  My problem is that I can't figure out a way to compare the two without causing an error, which I need to do.

Comment: what if you do something else, e.g.`if search_name in listofpersons`

Comment: Is indexing an issue here? I say this since i believe `first` and `last` and `middle` have to do with indexing

Comment: @Pondlen how are you expecting them to compare? Are you trying to compare the LENGTH of the string? What should `2 > "Adam"` be?

Comment: @Adam I believe the assignment is basically just a search inside a list, so its not comparing the string length.

Comment: @interwebz (I know what the problem is. I've implemented a binary search before! I'm trying to get him to think critically about his code :P)

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the problem.

The binary search algorithm should be comparing the middle point of the sorted list (i.e. the "pivot") to the search term. Instead you're comparing the INDEX of the middle point of the list.

```
middle = names[(first+last)/2] # values of names at pivot idx
```

A better implementation would be:

```
def binary_search(needle, haystack):
    start, end = 0, len(haystack)-1
    while start < end:
        pivot_idx = (start + end) // 2
        pivot = haystack[pivot_idx]
        if needle == pivot:
            return True
        if pivot_idx == start:
            # edge case -- I'm sure a better algorithm
            # would write this into the while condition
            break
        if needle < pivot:
            end = pivot_idx
        else:
            start = pivot_idx
    return False
```

Is now a good time to talk about tests? Always write tests! Test driven development is REMARKABLY EFFECTIVE! You should be able to write the test before you write the function!

```
def test_bin_search():
    tests = [(2, [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], False),
             (3, [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], True),
             ("s", ['a','b','s','q'], True),
             ('anything', ['unsorted', 'lists', 'should', 'fail!'], False)]
    for test in tests:
        needle, haystack, result = test
        assert binary_search(needle, haystack) == result
# there are modules such as unittest and nose that do a much
# better job of this than just running a series of asserts,
# but they're generally beyond the scope of a beginning student
# who's not specifically looking to learn TDD! If you're interested,
# I've written up a gist that has a basic implementation:
# https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/cf2b57b218a4c978e82b
```

In fact if you run these tests, you'll see another case that I missed in my algorithm! I'll leave it as an exercise to you to implement that case :)

Comment: I knew indexing was an issue. +1

Comment: Enter name to search for: Ava Fischer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 6, in main
    index = binarySearch(names, searchName, SIZE)
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 21, in binarySearch
    middle = names[(first + last)/2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Comment: That's the new error I am receiving now.  I know the solution is probably simple, but I'm a complete newbie at programming and have been at this for hours so my brain is pretty much mush right now...  Lol.  I really appreciate the feedback though guys.

Comment: @Pondlen what's the difference between `3/2` and `3//2` ?

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  I know that the operand // takes away the numbers after the decimal point when dividing.  That fixed the previous error, but I hit another one...  Surprise Surprise.

Comment: Enter name to search for: Ava Fischer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 6, in main
    index = binarySearch(names, searchName, SIZE)
  File "C:\Python30\NameSrch.py", line 27, in binarySearch
    last = middle - 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Pondlen because now `middle` is the value, but you're referencing it here as the index. Maybe you need two variables?

Comment: @Adam Smith I am at a loss for a solution right now and I still need to make another program after this before 12.  Not to mention I would like to get to sleep soon...  Lol.  I really appreciate the help though, I'm just extremely crunched for time and am having a huge mental block right now.

Comment: @AdamSmith, 
In line:
assert binary_search(needle, haystack) == test
I think It should be:
assert binary_search(needle, haystack) == result
Right?